# Pointerup event isn't working correctly with Windows Phone 8.1 / IE11

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, internet-explorer-11

The `pointerup` event is not working correctly with Win Windows Phone 8.1 and Internet Explorer 11. I mean, it is triggered automatically (just after pointerdown), and not when your finger goes out.

I've done an **[example here](http://bl.ocks.org/Xatpy/raw/814d5df9e1911fd83e64/)**.

If you test it with desktop browsers or Android-Chrome or iOS-Chrome/Safai works correctly

Has anyone any workaround about it?

Comment: Tested with Nokia Lumia 625.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting a `pointercancel` event?

If you don't set the `touch-action` correctly, then `pointercancel` gets sent through immediately after `pointerdown`. I think this is because the browser thinks a manipulation such as scrolling has been initiated.

To avoid this we use:

```
html.is-pointer-events .touch-grip {
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    touch-action: none;
}
```

Note that we activate this rule *only* if we are using Microsoft pointer events, because otherwise the touch-action property interferes with other browsers (e.g. Chrome).

We add `is-pointer-events` to `document.documentElement.className` if `navigator.msPointerEnabled` is true (i.e. we add the class when we are using `onpointerdown` instead of `ontouchstart`). If you are using modernizr.js then it looks like it provides a `pointerevents` class you can use.

Unless you have a compelling need for them and you can afford to invest a lot into it, I would strongly recommend against supporting Microsoft pointer events. For us they have been an expensive headache for us to support, and the value returned has been minimal for us.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it :)